# trying to find the name of a particular data visualization technique

Tags: visualization, data-visualization

I'm having a hard time describing a Flash program that uses a sort of hub-spoke data visualization technique. As the user navigates to a particular term, any term that is directly related would be represented with a line extending outward from the current term to the related term. Similar to how spokes extend from the hub of a wheel.

Some popular examples of this are:

[Visual Thesaurus](http://www.visualthesaurus.com/)

[Google's Wonder Wheel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Searchology#Wonder_Wheel)

My question is: Is there a name for this kind of a visual navigation system?

I'm trying to find out everything I can about the methods of writing a good [whatever it's called] system, but am having a hard time finding the right search terms.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a [hyperbolic tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_tree).

[image: Wikipedia image of hyperbolic tree]
<sub>(source: [wikimedia.org](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/e/e2/BasicTree.png))</sub>

Comment: just curious, what would this structure be called if it were non-hierarchical? Say, d4 were connected to c4.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at this [Periodic Table of Visualization Methods](http://www.visual-literacy.org/periodic_table/periodic_table.html).  :)   I think it would be something similar to a semantic network or clustering diagram.

[KurweilAI.net](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raymond_Kurzweil) has a similar structure he somewhat over-dramatically calls "[The Brain](http://www.kurzweilai.net/brain/frame.html?startThought=Artificial%20Intelligence%20%28AI%29)" which is a semantic visualization.

Answer (score 1):

The data visualization community is still maturing, I have had similar problems with terminology.

I believe the technique you're referring to could be called the "[Hyperbolic Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HyperbolicTree)."  The [javascript infovis toolkit](http://thejit.org/) includes an implementation shortened to "HyperTree."